# (systemjs) xhr error (404 not found) loading http in angularJS2

Tags: angular

I have put all the functions which i am using in a new folder and i am trying to access it by importing all the functions in the component in which i am using. I am able to import the functions, and i am able to even implement that function in the component, but when i run the app, i am getting an 404 file not found error.
dont know what went wrong

```
import { pincodePattern, matchingPasswords, qualificationValidation, emailValidator } from '../functions/functions.validation'
```

When i run it i get an error like this

```
Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/functions/functions.validation
```

[image]

I am able to compile the project, any help on how to add the functions file into the component if this is not the right way

**UPDATE 1**

this is the component file code:

```
import { pincodePattern, matchingPasswords, qualificationValidation, emailValidator } from '../functions/functions.validation'


@Component({
    selector: 'template-form',
    templateUrl: '../app/template.html'       
})
export class AppComponent {
    registrationForm: FormGroup;             

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.registrationForm = fb.group({
            username: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)]],
            emailId: ['', [Validators.required,emailValidator]],
            qualification: ['', [Validators.required, qualificationValidation]],
            streetAddress: ['', Validators.required],
            town: ['', Validators.required],
            gender: ['', Validators.required],
            designation: ['', Validators.required],
            selCountry: ['', Validators.required],
            selState: ['', Validators.required],
            selCity: ['', Validators.required],
            dateofBirth: ['', Validators.required],
            pincode: ['', [Validators.required, pincodePattern]],
            password: ['', [Validators.required]],
            confirmPassword: ['', Validators.required],
        }, { validator: matchingPasswords('password', 'confirmPassword') })
    }
```

This is my folder structure

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your functions should also be placed inside a component. Make sure to export that component as well.Would help if you could share the functions file.

Comment: I have done that, but it is not working, as i mentioned in my question, i am being able to import all the functions from the location and i am able to compile it, but i am getting an error while i am trying to run

Comment: You would have mentioned your functions file in your module as well ?